# What is not span?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

In linear algebra it's known that the **span** of the set $S$, denoted Span($S$), is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$.

What I'm looking for is if anyone has ever thought about the opposite problem, that is:

"*How can I find the biggest subspace of V that is contained into S?*"

I can't find anything about it anywhere. 
Does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if $S$ is just a set, there are no guarantees it has a (nonempty) subspace inside it in the first place.

Comment: @rubikscube09 We should require maybe that S contains the zero vector. Then we have such guarantees. Right?

Comment: I think the answer is $V_1 + V_2 + ... $ where $V_i$ are all subspaces of V contained in S. That should be the biggest one.

Comment: @peter.petrov But this sum might not be contained in $S$.

Comment: @Mark I guess you're right.

Comment: @peter.petrov There is some theorem in literature?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about a subspace $W\subseteq S$ such that if $V\subseteq S$ is a subspace then $V\subseteq W$. Such a subspace might not even exist. For example, consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and take $S=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1+i\}$. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is a maximal subspace which is contained in $S$, and so if what you ask was true then the "biggest subspace" would have to be $\mathbb{R}$. But $i\mathbb{R}$ is also a subspace which is contained in $S$, and it is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't specify it but i'm working in the domain of booleans ($\{0,1\}^n$)

Comment: @Marco The same issue still applies. If $A,B$ are subspaces with neither containing the other, then there is no largest subspace contained in $A\cup B$. E.g. in your case take $n=2$ and $$S=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)\}=\langle (1,0)\rangle\cup\langle (0,1)\rangle.$$